# Uneven positioning of arrow heads

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-arrows, arrows

I am trying to position arrowheads in the middle of my segments with

```
draw[decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}] (A)--(B);
```

It seems to me that 0.5 refers to the tip of ">" but to the tail of "<" if I use it instead. As result, the placing of the arrow heads looks uneven to me, see below.

I could do manual adjustments to .5, but I am looking for a clean solution as I am drawing many diagrams with edges of different lengths, so sometimes I would need to use .4 and .6 and sometimes .45 and .55, etc.

EDIT: One possible fix would be to modify \arrow{<} and \arrow{>} so that"position" controls their center of mass, rather than the tip or the end of the tail. How can I do it?

Here is an example of what I am talking about:
[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen} %expl3}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, math, decorations.markings,arrows.meta,calc,shapes.misc}
\usepgfmodule{decorations}

\tikzset{edge/.style={line width=1.5}}

\begin{document}
\raisebox{-0.4\height}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzmath{\x=0.3; \y=0.6;}
    \fill[gray!20!white] (0,0)circle(.8);
    \clip (0,0)circle(.8);
    \coordinate (A) at (\x,\x);
    \coordinate (B) at (\x,-\x);
    \coordinate (C) at (-\x,-\x);
    \coordinate (D) at (-\x,\x);
    \draw[edge, decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{<}}},postaction={decorate}] (A)--(B);
    \draw[edge, decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}] (B)--(C);
    \draw[edge, decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{<}}},postaction={decorate}] (C)--(D);
    \draw[edge, decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}] (D)--(A);
    \draw[edge, decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{<}}},postaction={decorate}](A)--(\y,\y);
    \draw[edge,  decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}](B)--(\y,-\y);
    \draw[edge,  decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{<}}},postaction={decorate}] (C)--(-\y,-\y);
    \draw[edge, decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}] (D)--(-\y,\y);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Only 0.5 is needed.

Comment: @SimonDispa: \arrowreversed is good to know, but it doesn't resolve the issue that  the visual center of < is not at .5. It rather means that once I make one adjustment for < then I don't need another for >.

Comment: Use `\arrow{Computer Modern Rightarrow}` instead of `\arrow{<}`. It is not a proper arrow tip of the arrows.meta Library.

Comment: Thanks. However, in my quick testing \arrow{Computer Modern Rightarrow} looks and behaves exactly as \arrow{<}...

Comment: But the point of the tip in either direction is at 0.5 as you wanted.

Comment: The "position" of the Computer Modern Rightarrow refers to the tip, as for >. 
As I elaborated in the edit, I hope for an arrowhead and its inverse which are centered in their middle. If I have one, then I could use \arrowreversed for the other.

Comment: What is the advantage for you when using>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you can define a new arrow head by shifting it and then use it as defined previously. A quick example (colours are only to make it legible):

[image: decoration at 0.5]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen} %expl3}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, math, decorations.markings,arrows.meta,calc,shapes.misc}
\usepgfmodule{decorations}

\begin{document}

\def\myarr{{\arrow[xshift={1.525pt + 0.9625\pgflinewidth}]{>}}}
\def\myrevarr{{\arrow[xshift={0.525pt + 0.9625\pgflinewidth}]{<}}}

\tikzset{edge/.style={line width=1.5},
        arr/.style={decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\color{red}{\myarr}}},postaction={decorate}},
        arr'/.style={decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\color{blue}{\myrevarr}}},postaction={decorate}}
        }
        
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[orange!50] (0,0) grid (4,4);
    \draw[arr,edge] (0,0) -- (4,0);
    \draw[arr',edge] (0,1) -- (4,1);
    \draw[arr,edge,line width=4pt] (0,2) -- (4,2);
    \draw[arr',edge,line width=10pt] (0,3) -- (4,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The measurements used are from `pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex`. If you have to do it for other arrow tips, you'll have to adapt the code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The tip `Computer Modern Rightarrow`  behaves as you expected.

It was  added a red tip to show they are meeting at the center of the segment `AB`. (No manual adjustments required).

Use `\arrowreversed` instead of `\arrow`  to invert the direction of the arrow tip.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen} %expl3}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, math, decorations.markings,arrows.meta,calc,shapes.misc}
%\usepgfmodule{decorations}

\tikzset{edge/.style={line width=1.0}} % changed <<<<

\begin{document}
    \raisebox{-0.4\height}
    {\begin{tikzpicture}
            \tikzmath{\x=0.3; \y=0.6;}
            \fill[gray!20!white] (0,0)circle(.8);
            \clip (0,0)circle(.8);
            \coordinate (A) at (\x,\x);
            \coordinate (B) at (\x,-\x);
            \coordinate (C) at (-\x,-\x);
            \coordinate (D) at (-\x,\x);
            \draw[edge, decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrowreversed{Computer Modern Rightarrow[red]}}},postaction={decorate}] (A)--(B);  % added <<<<<
            \draw[edge, decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{Computer Modern Rightarrow}}},postaction={decorate}] (A)--(B);                   
            \draw[edge, decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{Computer Modern Rightarrow}}},postaction={decorate}] (B)--(C);
            \draw[edge, decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrowreversed{Computer Modern Rightarrow}}},postaction={decorate}] (C)--(D);
            \draw[edge, decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{Computer Modern Rightarrow}}},postaction={decorate}] (D)--(A);
            \draw[edge, decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrowreversed{Computer Modern Rightarrow}}},postaction={decorate}](A)--(\y,\y);
            \draw[edge, decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{Computer Modern Rightarrow}}},postaction={decorate}](B)--(\y,-\y);
            \draw[edge, decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrowreversed{Computer Modern Rightarrow}}},postaction={decorate}] (C)--(-\y,-\y);
            \draw[edge, decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{Computer Modern Rightarrow}}},postaction={decorate}] (D)--(-\y,\y);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by creating two styles to which you could pass the desired value as an argument?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen} %expl3}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, math, decorations.markings,arrows.meta,calc,shapes.misc}
\usepgfmodule{decorations}

\tikzset{edge/.style={line width=1.5},
        arr/.style={decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}},
        arr'/.style={decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{<}}},postaction={decorate}}
        }

\begin{document}
\raisebox{-0.4\height}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzmath{\x=0.3; \y=0.6;}
    \fill[gray!20!white] (0,0)circle(.8);
    \clip (0,0)circle(.8);
    \coordinate (A) at (\x,\x);
    \coordinate (B) at (\x,-\x);
    \coordinate (C) at (-\x,-\x);
    \coordinate (D) at (-\x,\x);
    \draw[edge, arr=.65] (A)--(B);
    \draw[edge, arr=.6] (B)--(C);
    \draw[edge, arr'=.65] (C)--(D);
    \draw[edge, arr=.6] (D)--(A);
    \draw[edge, arr'=.6](A)--(\y,\y);
    \draw[edge,  arr=.5](B)--(\y,-\y);
    \draw[edge,  arr'=.65] (C)--(-\y,-\y);
    \draw[edge, arr=.6] (D)--(-\y,\y);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image: decoration with arg]

Comment: You abbreviated my code, but what I hope for is tikz code where .5 means the visual center of the arrow, without guessing whether it should be .55 or .6.

Comment: OK, it was not clear enough to me. I'm still not sure of what you really expect. This could depend on the actual arrow tip length, which is probably measurable.

Comment: I added an Edit. Even if the length of > is L, I still can't just simply replace 0.5 by 0.5+0.5L or 0.5-0.5L. So one solution would be to define new arrowheads which are like < and >, but shifted by L/2. Not sure how to do it though...